# Как получить параметры, передаваемые в Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script

Как можно взять параметр по имени, вроде:

```
var param1 = e.parameter.paramname1;
```

Скрипт вызывается так по адресу:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/.../exec?c1=someval&k1_1=someval&k1_2=someval&c2=someval
```

Как получить значения параметров c1,k1_1,k1_2,c2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В скрипте должно быть

```
function doGet(e){
  ...
}
```

При запросе

```
GET https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?p1=2&p2=3
```

параметр `e` будет содержать помимо прочего

```
{
  contentLength: -1
  contextPath: ""
  parameter: {
    p1: "2"
    p2: "3"
  }
  parameters: {
    p1: [1]
    p2: [1]
  }
  queryString: "p1=2&p2=3"
}
```

Получение значений параметров

```
var p1 = e.parameter.p1;
```